# Concatenando array usando un bucle

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema, el siguiente array: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` debo de recorrerlo y obtener el siguiente resultado `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. Actualmente obtengo el mismo resultado. Aquí mi código:

```js
let principal= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

let result= [].concat(
  principal.map((e)=>{
    return e
  })
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías conseguirlo a través de las funciones `reduce()` y `concat()`. Con `reduce()` podemos iterar el array principal para operar con cada uno de los arrays interiores e ir almacenando el resultado en una variable acumuladora. Con `concat()` hacemos que cada array interior se vaya "juntando" en la variable acumuladora para finalmente devolverse como un nuevo array.

```js
const principal= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
const result = principal.reduce((acumulador, item) => acumulador.concat(item))

console.log(result)
```

**Referencias:** [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 2):

Tambien encontre esta solucion:

```js
let arrays= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
let merged = [].concat.apply([], arrays);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra solucion prodria ser esta:

```js
let principal= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

let result = []
principal.forEach(arr=> result.push(...arr)  )
console.log(result)
```